# Eclipse Team Synchronize shows Outgoing changes in 'Java Workspace' Model, where Git Model shows none

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I've looked at the answers to similar questions here, and none fit the bill, or manage to solve the issue.

Using Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3) with EGit 4.7.0, and no other versioning system like SVN or CVS, calling *Team > Synchronize* on some of my Java projects, which have been synced with a Bitbucket repo many times over, and which show absolutely no changes whatsoever in the compare editor, including any whitespace differences, Eclipse still lists several .java source files as Outgoing changes under the "Java Workspace" model.

So for instance, calling *Team > Synchronize* on a project in my workspace, that is tracked in my local Git repo and remotely in a Cloud hosted Bitbucket, returns the following message:

> There are no more Incoming/Outgoing changes for Git Commits. However Java Workspace has changes in Incoming/Outgoing mode.
>
> Change to Java Workspace
>   Show All Models

[image]

A Google search for *"However Java Workspace has changes"* only yields a single result:

[image]

The [sole hit is a reported bug in Subversive](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=329555) (one of the two main SVN integrations for Eclipse). However, while the described issue sounds like a rather accurate match of the issue I'm having, it claims that doing another *Team > Synchronize*, or restarting Eclipse would resolve the phantom Outgoing changes. Not so in my case, not with EGit.

Like I said, the remote and local files are exactly the same, incl. their whitespace/line endings.
Fetch/Pull from origin says there are no changes, everything is up to date.
Calling *Replace With > HEAD Revision* also doesn't help, Eclipse keeps insisting, that my workspace has Outgoing changes. **Outgoing where?**

This is obviously no big issue, merely an irritating nuissance. Still would be nice to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I have same issue looks like eclispe team give up the fixing?. use sourcetree or git commandline instead

Answer (score 0):

...Did you try doing the Eclipse dance?

Edit: I find after some time Eclipse will behave strangely (example: dumping views I have enabled, losing track of files, or behaviour similar to what you are experiencing). When this happens I usually select and delete the project from my workspace, close Eclipse, reopen it and reopen the project.

I don't know why this happens or why this works as a fix.

Comment: Constantly having the same issue (and therefore am not fond of this Synchronization view of eclipse). Anyway it helped to restart eclipse with `eclipse -clean`, but cannot guarantee that's the ultimate solution.